# Where are Window Layouts stored?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am migrating from Windows 7 to a fresh Windows 10 build, I am now trying to migrate all my Visual Studio settings (2015 Community Edition on both machines). Import/Export settings has worked fine for the majority of things, but I previously set up several window layouts on the old machine, using the 'Window\Save Window Layout' menu - how do I copy these across ?

Import/Export settings has an option for Window Layouts but as far as I can tell this just exports the default one, not all the custom defined ones.

Are they in the .suo file, if so is it safe for me to just copy that across?

Comment: Yes, .suo file.  No, the format is not compatible and is now saved in a hidden .vs/projname/v14 subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure?  As that would mean the window layouts are associated to a specific solution and not global, and that does not appear to be the case.